# Dropping packets on tethering on Nexus 5X

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, tethering, wifi-tethering

During tethering on my "Nexus 5X" phone seems like lot of packets being dropped:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 40
Request timeout for icmp_seq 41
64 bytes from 213.180.204.3: icmp_seq=42 ttl=51 time=114.997 ms
64 bytes from 213.180.204.3: icmp_seq=43 ttl=51 time=109.585 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 44
Request timeout for icmp_seq 45
Request timeout for icmp_seq 46
Request timeout for icmp_seq 47
Request timeout for icmp_seq 48
Request timeout for icmp_seq 49
64 bytes from 213.180.204.3: icmp_seq=50 ttl=51 time=53.464 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 51
64 bytes from 213.180.204.3: icmp_seq=52 ttl=51 time=87.195 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 53
Request timeout for icmp_seq 54
Request timeout for icmp_seq 55
64 bytes from 213.180.204.3: icmp_seq=56 ttl=51 time=86.520 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 57
```

I used "Nexus 5" before with exactly the same sim card and the same mobile operator and the same laptop before and did not have (rather, did not notice) any similar issues.

Android version "6.0.1". I use Mac Pro with OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

Comment: I'm also seeing similar issues after upgrading to 6. There's a thread here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193680